# How to seize 1 resource unit and not the entire resource pool for downtime tasks

Tags: anylogic

I have a resource pool which contains 2 units. I also have a downtime defined for this resource pool. When the downtime is triggered, the entire resource pool of 2 units gets seized by the downtime task. However, I want only 1 unit of the resource pool to be seized by the downtime task. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on your downtime block you have option to select the number of units in the "downtime task" at property window. type "1" there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).